# recreating the ipad search bar in the contacts app

Tags: ios, search, uisearchbar

In the contacts app, the search bar is shown with a white background and it blends in well with the surrounding UI.  The only style choices in Interface Builder don't seem to show a way to host just the search bar, but instead includes chrome around it to make it look slightly 3d.

Is there a way to get rid of the surrounding chrome and simply have the search bar overlaid on my own view's background (which happens to be flat black)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the UIBarStyleBlack `.barStyle`, or set the `.tintColor` to black, or set the `.translucent` to YES.

However, there's no documented way to change the background *image* of a search bar.

You may use a UITextField with a custom `.background` and `.leftView` to simulate the look of a UISearchBar.